# Find all stored procedures including a text in their body

Tags: sql-server

I saw some answers about search text in stored procedures name, Id and etc. But I don't find out that what is the good way to find all stored procedures including the SQL of their body

More info: I have a table called X; I wand to drop it and I want to be sure that it has not been used in stored procedures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will find all procedures, functions, triggers, etc with the text `X`in it

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       o.name AS Object_Name,
       o.type_desc,
       m.*
FROM   sys.sql_modules m
  INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON m.object_id = o.object_id
WHERE m.definition Like '%X%'
```

It is easy to alter so you only get procedures, or whatever you need